sharedArrayBuffer conflict with firebase & CORS headers
I am able to get sharedArrayBuffer to work on mobile browsers with the following code in my htaccess (desktop works fine):
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "require-corp"
     Header set Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy "same-origin"
</IfModule>

But, with the following code I am unable to get firebase data to load.
I cant seem to find what the conflict is and hope somebody can help me resolve this.
